# loadMigrationsFrom method is not working in lumen

Tags: laravel, database-migration, lumen

I m working in the lumen framework, I have two directories under database/migrations each directory has its own migration files,
Then I have overridden the boot method inside app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
    public function boot()
{
    $this->loadMigrationsFrom([
        database_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'migrations' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'zendesk',
        database_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'migrations' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'clockify',
    ]);
}
```

When I run the command `php artisan migrate:fresh` it shows the messages

1: Dropped all tables successfully,

2: Migrations created successfully

3: Nothing to migrate

however, I created a new laravel 8 project and put both directories inside the migration directory override boot method inside AppServiceProvider, and run the same command and now all migrations run successfully and I can see tables in the database.
can someone please help me with how to do this in lumen? do I have to un-comment something in bootstrap or anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by just uncommenting
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
inside bootstrap/app.php